# Error executing data process; Caused by: Premature end of file. (in groovy script); Caused by: Premature end of file

Tags: groovy, boomi

I am getting the above error in the groovy script in boomi Please help me!! Below is the code.I am trying to format to xml. Data process is throwing this error.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import com.boomi.execution.ExecutionUtil;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
// Retrieve a handle to the Logger
logger = ExecutionUtil.getBaseLogger();

InputStream io = dataContext.getStream(0);
Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(0);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line);
}
def text = sb.toString();
text = text.replaceAll('&lt', '')
text = text.replaceAll('&gt', '')

def xmlStream = new XmlParser().parseText(text);
def data = xmlStream.data;

def result = "<records>"
for (child in data) {
  def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
  new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(stringWriter)).print(child)
  result = result + stringWriter.toString();
}
result = result + "</records>"
def childIO = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes());
dataContext.storeStream(childIO, props);
```

Comment: That looks like Java, not Groovy...  Is it Groovy?

Comment: Removed tags for Javascript and Java (assuming this is Groovy)

Comment: What are your inputs?  From the code above, it looks like you're trying to brute-force some XML into another XML document?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. It is groovy and I am trying to Extract and decode XML

Comment: please provide a stacktrace, if it makes sense and provide your input data, so we can reproduce the bug

Comment: this code is failing 1st time and when it is executed second time it is working perfectly

Comment: What is in `dataContext.getStream(0);`?  Your code could be cleaned up considerably, but I'd need to know this before I can help in a helpful fashion

Comment: this code is written by some one and here we are trying to extract data using HTTP SOAP. is this error related to this?

Comment: That's not an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Unless the input data with profile is given in this question, it will be difficult to answer it. However from the code, it seems that an extra parent node is being created  to the input XML. 
 This can easily be achieved by a Message component in Boomi. 
 Use a message shape and input the following: 
 `<records>{1}</records>` and form the parameters option in Message shape, use Current Data. This will give the same output for all your documents which you are trying to achieve from code. 
 In case if it does not fulfill your requirements please provide more details like input profile with fields and expected output.